# how to pass parameter to URL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I need to pass the parameters to URL.I have posed the code.

How can I pass the `username` and `password` entered in the textbox to URL in my code.thanks for any help..

Comment: it's not `java` `script`. It's `javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not send `password` in the URL.

If you want to pass some other details: Update these two lines as below:

```
             data: {data1:$("input#data1").val(),data2:$("input#data2").val()},
             url: "http://localhost:53179/hdfcmobile/hdfc.ashx",
```

Comment: You mean type. if yes, you have already written it -- type: 'POST',

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass a url parameter, the you want to use:

```
type: 'GET'
```

and also:

```
url: 'http://localhost:53179/hdfcmobile/hdfc.ashx
```

into the .ajax configs, using type:'POST' will post the fields into the headers instead of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

You can try your code in this pattern...

```
var sdate = $('#banners_startdate').val();

var edate = $('#banners_enddate').val();

        if(sdate != '' && edate != ''){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'your url',
                data: 'apiname=get_banner_stat_platform_sharing&var=bannerstats&sdate=' + sdate + '&edate=' + edate,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data){ 
                                         $('#bannerstats').html(data);
                                          return false;
                                       }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where username and password can be fetch by id:

```
function ajaxcall(username,password)
   {
         jQuery.ajax({

                      type: "POST",

                      url: "Enter Url to pass",

                      data: {user: username, pass: password},

                      dataType: "html",

                      success: function(data) {
                          //write code what you want to do here
                      }

         });

   }
```

You can fetch the value on page by just `$_POST['user']` and `$_POST['pass']`.